# Javascript, repeating an object key N-times, being N its value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering how to do this in the more cleaner and optimal way:

I have an Object with the following structure:

```
{
   "125": 2,
   "439": 3,
   "560": 1,
   "999": 2,
   ...
}
```

I want to create a flat array repeating every key, the number of times indicated by its value. And bonus points for converting keys (strings) to integers. In this example, the resulting array should be:

```
[ 125, 125, 439, 439, 439, 560, 999, 999 ]
```

I've tried several ways but they all look over-engineered. For sure there is an easier way.
This is what I've got with underscore (and it returns an Array of strings, nor integers):

```
_.compact(_.flatten(_.map(files, function(num, id) { 
     return new Array(num+1).join('$'+id).split('$') 
})))
```

I know there are plenty of ways to accomplish this. I just only want a clean and quick way. Being a **Ruby** developer it could be as easy as:

```
> files = {"125" => 2, "439" => 3, "560" => 1, "999" => 2}
 => {"125"=>2, "439"=>3, "560"=>1, "999"=>2} 
> files.map {|key, value| [key.to_i] * value}.flatten
 => [125, 125, 439, 439, 439, 560, 999, 999]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  "125": 2,
  "439": 3,
  "560": 1,
  "999": 2
}

var arr = [];

for (prop in obj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj[prop]; i++)
    arr.push(parseInt(prop));
}

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is plain JavaScript but seems cleaner to me than the code you posted:

```
var dict = {
   "125": 2,
   "439": 3,
   "560": 1,
   "999": 2
}
var result = [];

for(key in dict)
    for(i = 0; i < dict[key]; i++)
        result.push(key * 1);

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not sure if I got at, but maybe something like this:

```
var myObj = {
   "125": 2,
   "439": 3,
   "560": 1,
   "999": 2
},
myArray = [];

for(k in myObj){
    for(i = 0; i < myObj[k]; i++){
        myArray.push(k);
    }
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Correct, except that he wanted integers, so you should use `parseInt()` or something similar before adding the values to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Whether any of these approaches is cleaner is quite subjective:

```
// some helper function for creating an array with repeated values
function repeat(val, times) {
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i = arr.push(val));
    return arr;
}

function convert(obj) {
    var result = [], key;
    for(key in obj) {
        result = result.concat(repeat(+key, obj[key]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or a more functional approach:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result, key) {
    return result.concat(repeat(+key, obj[key]));
}, []);

// with underscore.js
_.reduce(_.keys(obj), function(result, key) {
    return result.concat(repeat(+key, obj[key]));
}, []);
```

Comment: `push` returns the new length, so I think you'll need to add `obj[k]` to `l` each iteration.

Comment: none of your examples can work. Also it's a bit difficult to read, converting strings into ints by doing an easily missed + operation and using a weird while loop doesn't really help.

Comment: @Vahur: They work perfectly after I fixed some minor errors. If you don't like the unary `+`, well, that's your opinion ;) Anyways, I changed it a bit to make it more expressive.

Comment: To know the reason for the downvote would nice, otherwise I cannot improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the other answers above is that the for..in language construct in javascript is going to involve all keys from the objects prototype chain. In this case, we should check and add only the correct keys.

```
var obj= {
   "125": 2,
   "439": 3,
   "560": 1,
   "999": 2
}

var arr=[];

for (var item in map) {
  //important check!
  if (map.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    arr.push(item);
  }
}
```

Also see: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/

Comment: You have a point, but that would only happen if the prototype of `Object` was extended. Doing that is usually frown upon, and some well-known libraries do not support running under such conditions. It's quite understandable, since supporting it implies applying your answer every time one iterates over an object (and costs a call to `hasOwnProperty()` for each iteration).

Comment: well I am assuming his flattening code receives an object as a parameter which for all intents and purposes may be coming from a prototyped object. As to weighing the 'cost' to call hasOwnProperty vs the function behaving correctly, I think it is safe to say which one is the safer choice. I resent having to do that check myself but that is how the javascript construct works.

Answer (score 0):

A helper function:

```
function flatten(obj){
 //static Array method: create array (a elements, value b) 
 Array.aXb = Array.aXb || function(a,b){
    b = b || 0;
    return String(this(a)).split(',').map(function(){return b;});
 }
 //obj2array 
 var arr = [];
 for (var k in obj)
    if (+obj[k]) arr = arr.concat(Array.aXb(+obj[k],k));
 return arr;
}
var obj= {"125": 2,"439": 3,
          "560": 1,"999": 2 },
flatten(obj); //=> [125,125,439,439,439,560,999,999]
```